Computing Semivalues for the Banzhaf Index
I am currently working through this paper that defines the semivalue for a particular game. However, I seem to be having some trouble figuring out how to get the correct semivalue. The definition is as follows:

Notation: We write $wt(x)$ to denote the weight a boolean vector (i.e. the number
of 1's).
Definition: For a positive integer $n$, a probability vector
$p^n = (p_0^n,\ldots,p_{n-1}^n)\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector such that
$\sum_{t=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{t}p_t^n = 1$ and $p_t^n\geq 0$. The $i$-th semivalue
corresponding to the probability vector $p^n$ of a Boolean function
$f:\{-1,1\}^n\to \{-1,1\}$ is defined to be
$$\tilde{f}^{p^n}(i)= \sum_{x\in\{-1,1\}^n:\, x_i = -1} p^n_{wt(x)}f(x)x_i + \sum_{x\in\{-1,1\}^n:\, x_i = 1} p^n_{wt(x)-1}f(x)x_i$$
for $i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}.$

This is all well-and-good, but I can't seem to get the expected semivalues out of this definition. Consider the weighted voting game $\nu = [3;2,1,1]$ and suppose that we would like to compute the Banzhaf index. It is not to hard to show that the vector of semivalues should then be $\left(\tfrac{3}{4}, \tfrac{1}{4}, \tfrac{1}{4}\right)$ (also confirmed in this paper in Example 3.3 and in this paper in remark 3.5 b).
However, when I go to compute the semivalue, everything seems to be going wrong. For this game, it seems natural to take the function $f$ to be
$$
f = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } w\cdot (x > 0) \geq 3\\
-1 & o.w.
\end{cases}
$$
where $w = (2,1,1)$ and $(x > 0)$ is the vector $(\mathbf{1}_{x_i > 0})$. So
$$
\begin{align*}
f(1,1,1) &= 1\\
f(1,1,-1) &= 1\\
f(1,-1,1) &= 1\\
f(1,-1,-1) &= -1\\
f(-1,1,1) &= -1 \\
f(-1,1,-1) &= -1 \\
f(-1,-1,1) &= -1\\
f(-1,-1,-1) &= -1.\\
\end{align*}
$$
Then when we go to compute the semivalue using the Banzaf probablility vector of $\left(\tfrac{1}{4}, \tfrac{1}{4}, \tfrac{1}{4}\right)$ (given in the remark on page 3 of the paper I am reading and verified elsewhere), we see that the semivalue for player 1 is
$$
\frac{1}{4}\left[-4\right](-1) + \frac{1}{4}\left[2\right](1) = \frac{6}{4}
$$
which is definitely not correct. I have also tried the obvious linear threshold functions, but run into similar issues. Can anyone tell what is going on here? I have seen this formula in several papers, so I doubt that it is wrong at this point, but I can't seem to get it to work with even simple examples. Thank you in advance for the help!
